How to extract some occurences in XML source with Talend routes / Camel
I need in a Talend route to keep only the occurences of an XML message body that have a specific value.
Example : If I required for T1 occurences,
<root>
<occ>
<name>A</name>
<type>T1</type>
</occ>
<occ>
<name>B</name>
<type>T1</type>
</occ>
<occ>
<name>C</name>
<type>T2</type>
</occ>
</root>

Should give me
<root>
<occ>
<name>A</name>
<type>T1</type>
</occ>
<occ>
<name>B</name>
<type>T1</type>
</occ>
</root>

kept in 1 message, not split per occurence.

In talend or using Camel ?

In Talend esb, that is based on Camel

Did you try using xml processors ? Or do you need some code example how to use camel with Talend ?

I can use Talend and Camel. I need a way to achieve this in a route. What are the xml processors you're talking about ? Is it a kinf of java code called in a cProcessor component ?
